# Doing drugs vs having breakfast

Tags: word-usage

Why do we *do* drugs but *have* food? Or even *have* a beer, which is alcoholic beverage thus a sort of drug too. In both cases we consume something. Is there a rule for this?

Comment: Also note that we could *take tea*.  Or *take drugs* for that matter.

Comment: If ketamine's your thing then you can do drugs and have breakfast at the same time.

Comment: boehj, I guess the same counts for _doing_ (or is it _having_) a wake and bake..

Comment: @TweeZz - Ha ha... yeh I guess so. :)

Comment: A question with this title would be way funnier on the Health and Fitness site..

Comment: I admit, I clicked because of the title

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, it gets even more curious than that. We can "have lunch" or we can "eat lunch" or we can even "do lunch":

> We need to talk. Let's do lunch. How's Thursday?

Add to that phrases like:

> Beer me.

This means "Give me/get me/hand me a beer."

There's really no rule you can apply to idiomatic expressions like these. Non-native speakers just have to learn them one by one, and they can be extremely vexing at times. It's enough to drive you to drink!

Comment: Doing lunch? I thought only marketing people did that, not real human beings.

Comment: Also, of course, idioms vary from place to place.  You may carefully learn "Hit me" meaning "Give me a beer" in a US bar, but if you use it in my local the barmaid will probably shrug and punch you (particularly if you are a marketing person).